# How to find what are the permissions a certain app is asking and using?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know there are a few types of permissions: Normal permissions, Signature permissions, Dangerous permissions and Special permissions.
It seems that **packages.xml** contains part of the permissions that a certain app is using, but, I’m not sure that it contains all the permissions the app uses.

1. Where can I find all of those permissions?
2. Where can I find all the data that an app can receive from my phone by having a specific permission?
   i.e. What data can app get from having the following permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

This is the output from the packages.xml file:

```
<perms>
    <item name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.INTERNET" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.VIBRATE" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" granted="true" flags="0" />
    <item name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" granted="true" flags="0" />
</perms>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the Settings -> APPS -> Managed Apps -> App that you want to see -> Permissions